# How do I diagnose "unable to create socket"?

Tags: r, rstudio

Suddenly RStudio is giving me this error when I enter a string on the help search box:

```
starting httpd help server ...Error in tools::startDynamicHelp() : unable to create socket
```

I get the same error when I enter the following on the console:

```
> ?grep
```

I have updated to the current version of RStudio and was running the current version of R.  I tried the same command in R itself and there's no problem.

Maybe coincidentally, when I try to get RStudio to update packages, I get this message:

```
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.1
```

Here is what RStudio provides in a diagnostics-report file:

19 Jul 2014 17:13:51 [rsession-John Smith] ERROR r error 4 (R code execution error) [errormsg=Error in tools::startDynamicHelp() : unable to create socket|||]; OCCURRED AT: core::Error r::exec::::evaluateExpressionsUnsafe(SEXPREC*, SEXPREC*, SEXPREC**, r::sexp::Protect*) C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\r\RExec.cpp:145; LOGGED FROM: core::Error session::modules::help::initialize() C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\session\modules\SessionHelp.cpp:894

I have **UNINSTALLED** R and RStudio and then re-installed and the problem doesn't go away.  Now when I launch RStudio, I get:

```
Error in tools::startDynamicHelp() : unable to create socket
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, one answer is to just try anything -- even something that appears quite remotely possible.  It turns out that that this mysterious and very irritating bug only happens in the 64-bit version of R (within RStudio), not the 32-bit version! Here's how to fix the problem:
 [image: Chose the 32-bit version of R]

Selecting the 32-bit version solves it!  **RStudio is SO great**, it is a huge bummer for its help system to not be working!

Comment: David Smith, in your answer you mention that it only happens in R studio. I have encountered the same error in regular and different versions of 64 of R. Pretty lost in this regard.

Comment: Besides this is not a solution specialy if you need to work with large databases

Comment: I've since switched to a Mac, but as far as I could tell, the problem occurred because I had (ineptly) installed *both* the 32 and 64 bit versions.  That led to all kinds of complications, like to versions of Java and the problems described here.  When I completely eliminated any trace of a 32-bit version, the problem cleared up.

Comment: I infer that you think 32bit caused the 64 problem? So I will try that one, thanks

Comment: The problem is having *both* 32 and 64 bit programs on the same machine at the same time.  There is probably no reason to have them both, and in retrospect I think it was foolish of me to install them both.  My suggestion: install the 64 bit program and make everything work with it: Java, Rstudio, etc.

Comment: I have this problem on a PC.  I was also having problems with loading packages.  I could not get 64 bit to run even w/ 32 bit uninstalled.  Setting Rstudio to use 32 bit resolved these issues.

Comment: For anyone else that stumbles across this post, like me 4 years after this thread, I have the exact same problem and can only run 32.