# R help error : Error in startDynamicHelp(TRUE)

Tags: r

I am new to R and getting below error message when I run ?mpg command in R console.

*starting httpd help server ...Error in startDynamicHelp(TRUE) : internet routines cannot be loaded*

I am running R version 3.4.1 on mac os Sierra.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a conflict between 64-bit and 32-bit versions of R.

Have you tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853799/how-do-i-diagnose-unable-to-create-socket)

Also, try running R.Version() to check the version and sys details.

Comment: Thanks! This did not solve the issue, so i did uninstall and re-install R which solved the issue.