# Error in importing Datasets in R

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to import an excel dataset on my work laptop and I encounter the below error.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I diagnose "unable to create socket"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24853799/4996248)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Will you please copy the text from the image into the question itself.  It will help other people find your question better, and perhaps suggest previous occasions where it's been asked before.

Comment: related to the comment about image of error : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557